# Azul Zing gc collection

Tags: garbage-collection, jvm, azul-zing

We are investigating an application running of azul jvm (Zing release : 1.7.0-zing_15.05.3.0-b3-product-azlinuxM-X86_64).
Would appreciate with some pointers on making sense of the gc logs on Zing.
JVM flags - `

```
-Xmx48g -XX:+ConcurrentDeflation -XX:+ScanSystemDictionaryBeforeUnload -XX:-ClassUnloading -XX:+KeepSafepointsInCountedLoops -XX:+UseOptimizedCollectionsIterator` 
-XX:StringTableSize=100019
```

We need to figure out if the JVM was struggling at any point with garbage - but do not know the exact keywords to fetch in the log.

Comment: Well, zing is a modified hotspot jvm. So either try the regular hotspot parameters or check their documentation or support forums.

Answer (score 2):

Your JVM flags show you're not generating GC log information.  To do this you will need to add the `-xloggc:[filename]` option.  You could also specify `-XX:+PrintGCDetails` to generate the detailed logging output.  You can find more details in the Zing documentation, http://docs.azul.com/zing/index.htm#ReferenceMaterials.htm.  There are sections on command line options and GC log files.